# How to get primary key of a system table in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, relational-database

I know one can query what is the primary key of a user table in Oracle database. But how can I do this for a system table, for example to know what is the primary key of `all_objects` table?

Answer (score 0):

There is not difference between "user tables" and "system tables" - their primary keys can all be queried from the data dictionary in the same fashion.

`all_objects`, however, is not a table - its a view. Therefore, it doesn't have a primary key, so you cannot query it.

Comment: so is there a way to know which columns uniquely identify an object in oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out what the actual table is first.

Do an explain plan on SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES;

You'll see a scan of SYS.OBJ$ - that's the table you're looking for.

A query of constraints of type 'P' from ALL_CONSTRAINTS doesn't show any entries for that table, so no primary key on that table.

I don't think this is your real question though. What are you really looking to get at?

By the way, views can actually have constraints defined on them, that's been a feature since 10g I believe.